# Python error of IndexError: too many indices for array when trying to subtracted the blue color using openCV

Tags: python, index-error

I face an IndexError when i try to substract the blue channel from the gray by using openCV

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Pictures/color2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)

gray[:,:,0] = 0
cv2.imshow('Blue Subtracted', gray)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow()
```

This is the error that i faced

```
gray[:,:,0] = 0
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I am using Python 3.7 with PyCharm Community

Comment: gray is a 2D array not 3D

Answer (score 0):

gray is a two-dimensional array with no depth you don't need to specify the channel

```
temp =  img[0,:,:] - gray
```

also, you should note that cv2.imread read as BGR, not RGB so the blue channel is the fist channel

Comment: Thanks, guys i found the way to solve my problem. I use   cv2.subtract()    to subtract the color and get the result that i want, eg.  ----  Blue = img[:,:,0]     ----   Result=cv2.subtract(Blue, gray)